# How to display joined tables in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, join, razor

I need to join few tables and display them in cshtml, but i got problem with model. I get error:

"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[DziennikASPTest4.Controllers.PROJEKTYController+ProwadzacyProjekty]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DziennikASPTest4.Models.ProwadzacyProjekty]'."

I have created query:

```
            var projekt = from p in db.PROJEKTY
                       join przedm in db.PRZEDMIOTY on p.id_przedmiotu equals przedm.id_przedmiotu
                       join prow in db.PROWADZACY on przedm.id_prowadzacego equals prow.id_prowadzacego
                       where prow.id_prowadzacego == 1
                       select new ProwadzacyProjekty
                       {
                           PROJEKTY = p,
                           PRZEDMIOTY = przedm,
                           PROWADZACY = prow

                       };
        return View(projekt);
```

and model:

```
    public class ProwadzacyProjekty
    {
        public PROJEKTY PROJEKTY { get; set; }
        public PRZEDMIOTY PRZEDMIOTY { get; set; }
        public PROWADZACY PROWADZACY { get; set; }
    }
```

and i try to display it in cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<DziennikASPTest4.Models.ProwadzacyProjekty>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     <div>@item.PROJEKTY.opis</div>
}
```

How should i suppose to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve your query with `.ToList()` before returning it to the view.

```
return View(projekt.ToList());
```

Also, check the namespace of the new model to ensure that you are creating the right type instead of a generated entity type.

```
select new DziennikASPTest4.Models.ProwadzacyProjekty
{
    PROJEKTY = p,
    PRZEDMIOTY = przedm,
    PROWADZACY = prow
};
```

Comment: Problem was with the namespace. Unbelivable.. Thx 4 help